# Can I set up different login types with Amazon Cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm working on a website where two different types of users would be signing up/in. Only one user overall can be logged in at a time, but depending on which type of user they are I'm going to need different login information. Will I need to use two different Cognito User Pools to get this done?

My app is written in React and as of right now I have the following

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react'


class App extends Component{
    //code 
}
export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

If you're not familiar with Amplify I'll explain that real quick. Basically I used that to get everything up and running as quickly as possible. Those packages essentially build a Cognito user pool along with a default login page straight from the Amplify cli. In the last line, wrapping App with "withAuthenticator" esentially means that the App won't run until after someone has logged in which is a feature I'd like to keep. The user should not see anything other than their respective login page before seeing actual content.

I'm thinking of having a separate page wrap around the export App line and from there have the user choose between two different user-types and then lead them to their correct login page. Is this a good way to go about this? Or am I missing something in terms of security or ease of implementation?

Answer (score 1):

i believe your case is pretty simple why don't you use cognito userpool groups to achieve the same thing, whenever a user with **role type A** logs in, redirect him to his respective landing-page same is the case with **role type B**.